# Schedulings pages after 24 hours based on registration date.

Tags: php, scheduled-tasks

I have a online course having 50 lessons.

Now what i want to achieve is that  each lesson is shown 1 day at a time or every 24 hours depending on the date the members are subscribed?
Note:- members Can  subscribed at different dates and times.

Any idea how can i achive that?

Comment: Hi, I can't really follow what you're asking here.  What are the rules to display a course?  Where is the code that you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this is a scheduled task, but more of a bit of logic in your php code that doesn't show the link for courses that are not accessible yet.

This should be fairly simple date processing based on a users registration date.

Here is a post on stack overflow for calculating date differences.

[PHP date calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388673/php-date-calculation)