# Countdown to sunday

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am currently looking at creating a script for my site that will count down to sunday of that week, every week.

Example:

The user visits the site on a saturday at 11:30am, they will be greeted with:

"The next time this page will be updated is in 0 days, 12 hours and 30 minutes."

Any ideas?

Comment: Hello @Repox, I have currently tried to takeaway the time() function output from a time() string I have set within the script, but that would then require me to constantly change that string every week, would be lovely to have it all automagic.

Comment: Please [read the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). You could solve this with code, but asking a question that says "Please code this for me" or "give me ideas how to do this [well-known problem]" is not a "real" question on SO.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I apologise for that, however was not asking to be spoonfed rather asking for how other people would go about doing it, but I will take your feedback and apply it to any future posts thanks!

Comment: A good search may be `php javascript countdown timer`. This is well-worn territory, with many different types of examples and approaches for different scenarios.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this little trick to get a timestamp for midnight next Sunday:

```
$sunday = strtotime('next Sunday');
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/389055/766580) for how to format it into something useful. Right now I get this:

```
print_r(dateDifference($sunday, time()));
Array
(
    [years] => 0
    [months_total] => 0
    [months] => 0
    [days_total] => 0
    [days] => 0
    [hours_total] => 4
    [hours] => 4
    [minutes_total] => 256
    [minutes] => 16
    [seconds_total] => 15387
    [seconds] => 27
)
```

Comment: Thank you, why did I not think fo strtotime() function, I already have it formatting into something useful, just needed it to automatically set the timestamp for the upcoming sunday, so thank you!

Comment: Love strtotime keep learning new stuff about it all the time!

Comment: @JakeBall No worries. Would you mind accepting my answer? Thanks.

Comment: This won't work in timezones different than that of the user, though.

Answer (score 2):

I am using similar to [this](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/time-ago-function/) solution in one of my pojects. You can use it like this:

`ago(strtotime("next sunday"))` but you need to change `$difference     = $now - $time;` to `$difference     = $time - $now;`

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/foxbunny/xBE7L/

It also automatically updates every second.

Edit: I've included the `offset` parameter, and you use it to supply the difference between user's and server's time-zone if necessary.